# updated json value not writing into file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read the existing JSON value and updating it with a new value in my test class but I'm not getting the expected output - it is not writing as a JSON object and updating with empty value in string format. Pleas find the code below:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const fileName = '../test.json'
    let fileContent = await readFile(fileName);
    fileContent.productID = 'prod12212';
    let updatedContent = await testWriteFile(fileName, fileContent);
    console.log(updatedContent)

});



const readFile = async (filePath) => {
  try {
    const result = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
    return result
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}


const testWriteFile = async (filePath, fileContent) => {
  try {
    console.log('filoe content value', fileContent)
    const result = await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(fileContent))
    return result
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**test.json**

```
{
    "productID": ""
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "productID": "prod12212"
}
```

But below output I'm getting, what mistake I'm doing here:

```
"{\n    \"productID\": \"\"\n}"
```

Comment: You just forgot the parse the JSON when you read the file.

Comment: What does beforeAll(....) function does here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, one of your problem is you are declaring function expression (const fn = () => { .... } ) and using them before they are declared. Function expressions are not hoisted that means you can't use them before they are declared. But if you declare a function ( function fn() { ... }) you can use it before its declaration.

Secondly, you're reading the file content in the before all function but you are not parsing it. It's just a plain string if you don't parse it.

After all, fs.promise.writeFile(....) returns Promise<void>! It doesn't return the updated file content.

Here's the modified code that worked for me.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const readFile = async (filePath) => {
  try {
    return await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, "utf8");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const writeFile = async (filePath, fileContent) => {
  try {
    fileContent = JSON.stringify(fileContent);
    await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, fileContent);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const updateFile = async () => {
  const fileName = "./test.json";
  let fileContent = await readFile(fileName);

  // Parse the file content as json and then update it
  try {
    fileContent = JSON.parse(fileContent);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // here fileContent is an object
  fileContent.productID = "prod12212";

  writeFile(fileName, fileContent);
};

updateFile();
```